# Bootstrap Tab Clears My Model when Hidden

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So I was converting a button group to a Bootstrap Tab and then one of my views stopped appearing. I could not figure out what I had done wrong but I think I've  narrowed it down to the Tab resetting my model when the Tabs are hidden. Here's what I have:

controller:

```
$ctrl.$onInit = function() {
    $ctrl.states = [ // for toggling which view to display
        'state0', // 0
        'state1', // 1
        ...
    ];
    $ctrl.currentState = $ctrl.states[3]; // this should show my forth view
};
```

View:

```
<!-- setting to false for testing --> 
<div class="panel-body desktop hidden-xs hidden-sm" ng-show="false"> 
    <!-- here I use currentState to determine which one is active -->
    <uib-tabset active="$ctrl.currentState" type="tabs" justified="true"> 
        <uib-tab heading="Some Text" index="'state0'">
            <div class="text-center text-primary">Fields Marked With * Are Required.</div>
        </uib-tab>
        ...
    </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

When the tabs are being hidden currentState gets set to "" and my other view doesn't display.

View2:

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-show="$ctrl.currentState === 'state4'">
    ...
<div>
```

How can I disable this behavior? I've done some research but I haven't found anyone with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess no one else has encountered this issue. I have found a work around though.

I added a new tab that I don't display.

```
<uib-tab heading="Some Text" index="'state4'" ng-show="false">
</uib-tab>
```

Since a tab exists now for this state my currentState variable doesn't get cleared. I'd love a better answer for this but it's at least functional now.